Why can't I type in on custom autocomplete popper with input
I can't write in the input label and year. In my application, I have a dropdown where I have an input for search and  two inputs for add a film (title and year). The main problem is that the focus is force on search input and I don't know how to overwrite this behavior on the input from label and year. If you need to test, please check the sandbox link!  What I tried to do:

I checked if I receive the correct data.
I change the defaultValue form Label into value.
I change the <input tag with input from Material Ui.

`Code where is the input for label and year`
            <AddOption>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Label"
                defaultValue={newFilm.label}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setNewFilm((prev) => ({ ...prev, label: e.target.value }))
                }
              />
              <input
                placeholder="Year"
                type="number"
                value={newFilm.year || ""}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setNewFilm((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    year: Number(e.target.value),
                  }))
                }
              />
              <button onClick={handleAddFilm}>Add</button>
            </AddOption>     

This is the link with full version: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quiet-bird-7zpl5n?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A55%2C9-90%2C24
